# Why can't I get the Cut HM in Pokemon Green?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I am playing Pokemon Green on my Game Boy Color (JAP).

I have beaten the first two gyms and went to the SS Anne. I beat the rival, talked to the captain, rubbed his back and left the ship. But I still don't have the Cut HM and the ship is still here.

Am I missing something?

---

I'm also pretty sure that the cartridge is original. I bought it in a Japanese retail store last year, but if anyone wants to check it out, here's some pictures:

[image: Pokemon Green cartridge front]
[image: Pokemon Green cartridge back]

Comment: In the [Pokemon Green beta](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red_and_Green_beta#Items), Cut is a TM. If you have a TM51, it should teach Cut same as HM01.

Comment: I know traditionally when you get on the SS Anne and talk to the Captain you rub his back to help him feel better from his sea sickness and he gives it to you. Is this by any chance a pirated version of it? If so it could explain why the event didn't happen for you. I suggest you go back and try again.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i have beaten the first two gyms and i've also rubbed the back of the captain, but he won't give me the HM. I'm also pretty sure that the cartridge is original, i bought it in a Japanese retail store last year, but if anyone wants to check it out i leave the links to the [images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g7vsilfgkyabhs7/AAAJkFkGP6FsT2p_yzitAheya?dl=0). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Cut HM, once finding your way to the top of the ship, and defeating your rival, the captain will say he's not feeling well, and ask you to rub his back. Make sure you exhaust his dialogue (you may be presented with a "Yes/No" choice, I'm not too sure. If you are, choose "Yes"). You will make him feel better, and he should reward you with the Cut HM (HM01), regardless.

The only restriction might be that you will need to beat Misty (Cerulean City Gym Leader) in order to obtain it, but I don't believe it's necessary. Defeating her allow you to use the HM outside of battle.

Answer (score 2):

Your inventory space is probably full.

Try tossing/selling items, moving them to the PC box, or using them on one of your Pokémon. That should free up some space. Then, interact with the captain again.